# jQuery POST of an array of objects to Node

Tags: jquery, node.js, arrays, post

I'm trying to use jQuery to send a POST request to my Node app, with an array of objects included in the data. When the request body reaches the server, the array data gets blown out into individual fields, leaving me without a way to use array functions.

Data Object

```
keyworddata = [
   {
     field1 : 'foo1',
     field2 : 'bar1'
   },
   {
     field1 : 'foo2',
     field2 : 'bar2'
   }
]

postdata = 
  {
    newtitle : 'New Title',
    newtopic : 'New Topic',
    keywords : keyworddata
  }
```

jQuery POST

```
function postNewData(senddata) {
  $.post("/data/add", senddata, function(data,status,xhr){
    //wanting to do some stuff here
  });
};

postNewData(postdata);
```

Controller Code - /data/add route sends the request to this function

```
exports.addNewData = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  //need to iterate over req.body.keywords as an array but can't
}
```

Console on the server displays - keyword array gets split into individual fields

```
{
  'newtitle' : 'New Title',
  'newtopic' : 'New Topic',
  'keywords[0][field1]' : 'foo1'
  'keywords[0][field2]' : 'bar1'
  'keywords[1][field1]' : 'foo2'
  'keywords[1][field2]' : 'bar2'
}
```

I've also tried to build the data using `stringify` and sending to the post request

```
keyworddata = [
   {
     field1 : 'foo1',
     field2 : 'bar1'
   },
   {
     field1 : 'foo2',
     field2 : 'bar2'
   }
]

postdata = 
  {
    newtitle : 'New Title',
    newtopic : 'New Topic',
    keywords : JSON.stringify(keyworddata)
  }
```

Using `stringify` the data arrives on Node like this

```
{
  'newtitle' : 'New Title',
  'newtopic' : 'New Topic',
  'keywords' : '[{"field1":"foo1","field2":"bar1"},{"field1":"foo2","field2":"bar2"}]'
}
```

This seems closer, but I can't run array functions against a string and I can't find a workaround to get this back to an array of objects.

I've also tried using an `$.ajax` call, but get the same results as above.

Comment: Try using `JSON.parse(string)` - this will work.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman  that's the answer.  i swear i researched this, but couldn't find an answer.  thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `JSON.parse(string)` will work. An example code is:

```js
const reqContent = {
  'newtitle': 'New Title',
  'newtopic': 'New Topic',
  'keywords': '[{"field1":"foo1","field2":"bar1"},{"field1":"foo2","field2":"bar2"}]'
};

const keywords = JSON.parse(reqContent.keywords);
console.log(keywords);
```